# Web kit Scroll bar border animation

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I want to give a glow effect fro my scroll bar.
Is there any web kit scrollbar border colour option?
any body knows?

```
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}


/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border:1px solid #eee;
}


/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #aaaaaa; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #eee; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which element you want to glow, but to get a 'glow' on any item you would use `box-shadow` with `x y radius spread color` you can ignore the spread if you want to and the color if you want the box-shadow to be black.

so:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 #000
```

is equal to:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1em;
```

So, if you want the complete scrollbar to glow:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #f00;
}
```

Or only the Thumb:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #aaaaaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #f00;
}
```

Comment: If this works for you, consider setting it as the accepted answer. If not, please explain so I can help you with any further questions.